# Intel HD Graphics (integrated) Minecraft graphical freezes and glitches - graphics driver or card?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, minecraft, integrated

I have a [Lenovo G570](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tech-specs/laptop/essential/g-series/g570/) laptop, which played Minecraft perfectly 1 or 2 months ago. Now, whenever I play the game, I'm faced with freezes, which sometimes crash Unity (with some error message like `intel_do_flush_locks() failed: blah`) and graphical glitches (a diagonal twisted segment of the screen occurred once). As I said, I don't know if this is a result of installing OpenCL drivers, a graphics card problem, or a software one.

Thanks in advance,
whiskers75

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that a software issue is the most probable cause.

**Gfx Driver:**
Perhaps a bug has been introduced with a Kernel update for your particular hardware. You can try starting your computer with an older kernel version see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) on how to , if you are uncertain

**Os Update:**
You can try the Ubuntu version you are currently using but booted of a USB stick. It will contain less recent updates. If you computer crashes often even from a live cd. Its could actually be a hardware problem.

Comment: I know all of this, but thanks for the answer :)